# Can not connect PAX

Tags: websphere, cognos-tm1

**Environment**

Planning Analyrtics Local 2.0.9.9

IBM Planning Analyrtics Spreadsheet Service(PAW) 2.0.66

IBM Planning Analytics for Microsoft Excel  2.0.66

Windows 64bit

When I install all the above software. I can login Architect, TM1 Web successful.

Below is my PLA configuration.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z61IC.png)

but when I try to use these URL to login. They donot work.

> http://localhost:9510/?pmhub&rest

> http://localhost:9510

> http://localhost:9510/pmpsvc

As I used the earlier version I can login PAX using the URl > http://localhost:9510/?pmhub&rest.
Why this version does not work?

Comment: TM1 application server gateway URI   http://localhost:9510/pmpsvc

Comment: External server URI   http://localhost:9510

Comment: to connectt PAX you need to go in Option in PAX and set the URL field with the PAW URL. Give us your PAW URL.

Comment: Thanks Wuzardor. But  I do not have PAW locally. As I used the earlier version of PAL and PAX. Without PAW locally I can also connect PAX. If this is the new version updated? If as you said, i will install PAW.....